# Textlocal is not sending out sms to my mobile number

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnPhone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string destinationphone = "+65" + txtPhone.Text;
    string message = "HELP! Someone Has Fell Down At Home. Please Rush Home To Check It.";
    string message1 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(message);

    using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] response = wb.UploadValues("https://api.txtlocal.com/send/?apikey=", new NameValueCollection()
        {
            {"apikey" , "cUgTLi57ieQ-cusJZXjMcFeLylqlZt105LVmuq6nTZ"},
            {"numbers" , destinationphone},
            {"message" , message1},
            {"sender", "TechSensor"}
        });
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    }
}
```

This is my current code for sending SMS to a number. However, it is not working for me. Please assist me if you use textlocal before. I am not using the textlocal.in as that is for India.

Comment: Could it be that textlocal is not functioning well now? I examined the codes and look up the internet. I don't think it is my coding error.

Comment: What modem are you using? How is it connected to the machine (USB, Ethernet)?  Is the Server your local machine or another machine?  Is modem on local machine or server?

Comment: are you sure your credentials valid? Just executing this code returns this in response:
`{"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}`

Comment: @Sharif yes. I checked the textlocal api message history. My message can be seen at there. Currently, the status for those sent message is just unknown. I searched online and stuff, a lot people are saying textlocal is not working at all for some reason.